# How to fill only one textbox from a modal when you have a lot of them

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I explain my issue, i have this code :

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-2">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "X"})
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
       @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dropdown1" })
   </div>

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-2">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "X_Y2"})
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dropdown2" })
   </div>
```

This modal :

```
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Multiples
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Valeur <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Valeur"/><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite1" /><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite2" /><br />
                    Opérant (+) <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Operand" /><br />
                    <br />
                    Valeur <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Valeur2" /><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite3" /><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite4" /><br />
                    Opérant (+) <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Operand2" /><br />
                    <br />
                    Valeur <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Valeur3" /><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite5" /><br />
                    Unité <input style="text-align:right;" type="text" id="Unite6" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Annuler
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="valueOK">
                        Valider
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my scripts :

```
    $(function () {
        $("#Dropdown1,#Dropdown2,#Dropdown3,#Dropdown4,#Dropdown5,#Dropdown6,#Dropdown7,#Dropdown8,#Dropdown9,#Dropdown10,#Dropdown11,#Dropdown12,#Dropdown13,#Dropdown14,#Dropdown15,#Dropdown16,#Dropdown17,#Dropdown18,#Dropdown19,#Dropdown20,#Dropdown21,#Dropdown22,#Dropdown23,#Dropdown24,#Dropdown25,#Dropdown26,#Dropdown27,#Dropdown28,#Dropdown27,#Dropdown28,#Dropdown29,#Dropdown30,#Dropdown31,#Dropdown32,#Dropdown33,#Dropdown34,#Dropdown35,#Dropdown36,#Dropdown37").change(function () {
            //Recupere la value de la liste
            selection = $(this).val();
            //Mettre la valeur du choix de liste.
            if (selection == 10) {
                //Affiche le modal
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });



var modalValue1 = $('#Valeur')
var modalValue2 = $('#Unite1')
var modalValue3 = $('#Unite2')

var modalOperand = $('#Operand')

var modalValue4 = $('#Valeur2')
var modalValue5 = $('#Unite3')
var modalValue6 = $('#Unite4')

var modalOperand2 = $('#Operand2')

var modalValue7 = $('#Valeur3')
var modalValue8 = $('#Unite5')
var modalValue9 = $('#Unite6')

$('#valueOK').click(function () {       
    $('#X').val(modalValue1.val() + modalValue2.val() + modalValue3.val() + modalOperand.val() + modalValue4.val() + modalValue5.val() + modalValue6.val() + modalOperand2.val() + modalValue7.val() + modalValue8.val() + modalValue9.val());
})
```

So that works pretty fine, when i put text in my textbox and after I press the button the information are going into the texbox in my page, that's ok. But if i try to apply this to other textboxes i have i'm facing a problem, if i fill the modal it will take this information and put it into every textbox of the page, but thats not what i want, how can i do for example to fill the first textbox with information and the second one with other information ?

Comment: Off Topic: small tip, dont use `$("#Dropdown1,#Dropdown2,...,#Dropdown37")`, instead, aply a class to every Dropdown and the select them as: `$(".myClass")`

Comment: About your problem, are u sure your id 'X' is unique?

Comment: Yes, because in this Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { class = "form-control", id = "X"}) the real name of X.Y is not that, the only real thing is the id i gave, and if you look my second text box, the id is X_Y2

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you want, you have lots of textbox and dropdown , if any one of the dropdownlist changed to 10 you want to show a dialog and after that fill the related textbox.

so, you coded too hard.
firstly,  use class selector instead id selector $("#DropDown1,#DropDown2,....")  -> $(".MyDropdown")

after that you can control you modal

for finding the nearest textbox you use closet or parent command in jquery.

it's just a solution, you can find lots of another solution to do that. like finding by data- Or aria- .

i hope it will be useful for you.

**EDIT**

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
     var targetTextBox=$(this).closest("div+ input").prev().find('input');
     BootstrapDialog.show({
        message: function(dialog) {
            var $message = $('<div></div>');
            var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
            $message.load(pageToLoad);

            return $message;
        },
        data: {
            'pageToLoad': 'remote.html'
        },
        buttons: [{
            id: 'btn-1',
            label: 'Click to disable and spin.',
            action: function(dialog) {
                targetTextbox='load your data';
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

this is an example, but you have to custom it for you.
and you have to use dialog box instead of modal

Comment: Thanks for thath but if i do this in my script :     $('#valueOK').click(function () {       
        $('#BoxSoinsCourants').val(modalValue1.val() + modalValue2.val() );
        $('#test').val(modalValue1.val() + modalValue2.val());
    }) my value will be in both but i want it in only one

Comment: actually you chose the hardest way. try to find nearest textbox from dropdown not by ID

Comment: something like this  ?    $('#valueOK').click(function () {
        $('selector').closest('dropdown');
        $('#BoxSoinsCourants').val(modalValue1.val() + modalValue2.val());})

Comment: Also i can't add a class to all my dropdown, if i do it, my modal won't show